# how to make a left and right div fixed and center div scrollable

Tags: css, css-float

In my webiste i have 3 divs.

```
<div class="main_div">
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="center"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

the class left  is float left and center is also float left and class right is float right.
how to make the left and the right class div fixxed and the center div can be scrolled like facebook.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to update properties like this..

```
.left{position:fixed;left:0px;float:left;}
.right{position:fixed;right:0px;float:right;}
.center{position:absolute;left:value;float:left;}
```

Comment: when i am applying  left:0px;the left  div is going at the left of the screen.. and same as