# Center div scroll and left ,right div fixed

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, alignment

I have created a layout in bootstrap grid format. I want my center div which is `col-md-6` should be scrollable and left and right div should be fixed. I have checked this question too [how to make a left and right div fixed and center div scrollable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17122579/how-to-make-a-left-and-right-div-fixed-and-center-div-scrollable) But when i tried this trick i'm not getting expected result because of bootstrap grid format.

Here is my HTML CODE :

```css
/* Using this CSS is giving me unexpected result.*/

.left {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  float: left;
}

.right {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0px;
  float: right;
}

.center {
  position: absolute;
  left: value;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
  LEFT DIV
</div>

<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
  MIDDLE DIV
</div>

<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
  RIGHT DIV
</div>
```

Any kind of help would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please add class `left,center,right` to html divs in posted code.

Comment: none of the answers conform to the proper bootstrap implementation, the purpose of using `col-sm-12 col-xs-12` for the columns is totally absurd.

Answer (score 1):

```css
/* Using this CSS is giving me unexpected result.*/

.outer_div{
  height:200px;
  overflow:auto;
  width:100%;
}

.left {
  position: fixed;
  float: left;
  height:100%;
  width:25%;
  
}

.right {
  position: fixed;
  float: right;
  height:100%;
  width:25%;
  right:0;
  
}

.center {
  float: left;
  width:50%;
  position:relative;
  left:25%;
  
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer_div">

<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
  <div class="left">Left Div</div>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
  
  <div class="center">
    MIDDLE Div
  <div>
    <p>Some Text</p>
    <p>Some Text</p>
    <p>Some Text</p>
    <p>Some Text</p>
    <p>Some Text</p>
    <p>Some Text</p>
    <p>Some Text</p>
  </div>
  </div>
  
  
</div>

<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
  <div class="right">Right Div</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Is this the same that you are looking for?

Hope this helps.

Comment: No bro. I dont want a scroll bar at middle of the page. I want that scollbar at the right most.

Comment: You have written in your question `I want my center div which is col-md-6 should be scrollable and left and right div should be fixed`. What does that mean?

Comment: @AryanShaw , Updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

use this code:-

**css :-**

```
.left_div {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.32);
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: justify;
    padding: 10px;
}

.right_div {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0px;
    float: right;
    border: 1px solid rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.32);
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: justify;
    padding: 10px;
}

.center_div {
    position: relative;
    text-align: justify;
    border: 1px solid rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.32);
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

**html :-**

```
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="left_div"> left div   </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="center_div">  left div  </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="right_div"> left div  </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There should be a much better solution somewhere else with a proper use of bootstrap

for e.g. **[Affix](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix)**, anyhow, here's my 2 cents.

```css
.container-fluid.main{
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
.left,.right{
  background-color: #ddd;
  min-height: 200px;
}
.center {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid main">
  <div class="row">
  
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
      <div class="left affix">
        <div class="well col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
          <h2>LEFT DIV</h2>
<p>Prow scuttle parrel provost Sail ho shrouds spirits boom mizzenmast yardarm. Pinnace holystone mizzenmast quarter crow's nest nipperkin grog yardarm hempen halter furl. Swab barque interloper chantey doubloon starboard grog black jack gangway rutters.</p><br />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
      <div class="center">
        <h2>MIDDLE DIV</h2>
<p>Prow scuttle parrel provost Sail ho shrouds spirits boom mizzenmast yardarm. Pinnace holystone mizzenmast quarter crow's nest nipperkin grog yardarm hempen halter furl. Swab barque interloper chantey doubloon starboard grog black jack gangway rutters.</p><br />
<p>Deadlights jack lad schooner scallywag dance the hempen jig carouser broadside cable strike colors. Bring a spring upon her cable holystone blow the man down spanker Shiver me timbers to go on account lookout wherry doubloon chase. Belay yo-ho-ho keelhaul squiffy black spot yardarm spyglass sheet transom heave to.</p><br />
<p>Trysail Sail ho Corsair red ensign hulk smartly boom jib rum gangway. Case shot Shiver me timbers gangplank crack Jennys tea cup ballast Blimey lee snow crow's nest rutters. Fluke jib scourge of the seven seas boatswain schooner gaff booty Jack Tar transom spirits.  </p><br />
<p>Prow scuttle parrel provost Sail ho shrouds spirits boom mizzenmast yardarm. Pinnace holystone mizzenmast quarter crow's nest nipperkin grog yardarm hempen halter furl. Swab barque interloper chantey doubloon starboard grog black jack gangway rutters.</p><br />
<p>Deadlights jack lad schooner scallywag dance the hempen jig carouser broadside cable strike colors. Bring a spring upon her cable holystone blow the man down spanker Shiver me timbers to go on account lookout wherry doubloon chase. Belay yo-ho-ho keelhaul squiffy black spot yardarm spyglass sheet transom heave to.</p><br />
<p>Trysail Sail ho Corsair red ensign hulk smartly boom jib rum gangway. Case shot Shiver me timbers gangplank crack Jennys tea cup ballast Blimey lee snow crow's nest rutters. Fluke jib scourge of the seven seas boatswain schooner gaff booty Jack Tar transom spirits.  </p><br />
<p>Prow scuttle parrel provost Sail ho shrouds spirits boom mizzenmast yardarm. Pinnace holystone mizzenmast quarter crow's nest nipperkin grog yardarm hempen halter furl. Swab barque interloper chantey doubloon starboard grog black jack gangway rutters.</p><br />
<p>Deadlights jack lad schooner scallywag dance the hempen jig carouser broadside cable strike colors. Bring a spring upon her cable holystone blow the man down spanker Shiver me timbers to go on account lookout wherry doubloon chase. Belay yo-ho-ho keelhaul squiffy black spot yardarm spyglass sheet transom heave to.</p><br />
<p>Trysail Sail ho Corsair red ensign hulk smartly boom jib rum gangway. Case shot Shiver me timbers gangplank crack Jennys tea cup ballast Blimey lee snow crow's nest rutters. Fluke jib scourge of the seven seas boatswain schooner gaff booty Jack Tar transom spirits.  </p><br />
<p>Prow scuttle parrel provost Sail ho shrouds spirits boom mizzenmast yardarm. Pinnace holystone mizzenmast quarter crow's nest nipperkin grog yardarm hempen halter furl. Swab barque interloper chantey doubloon starboard grog black jack gangway rutters.</p><br />
<p>Deadlights jack lad schooner scallywag dance the hempen jig carouser broadside cable strike colors. Bring a spring upon her cable holystone blow the man down spanker Shiver me timbers to go on account lookout wherry doubloon chase. Belay yo-ho-ho keelhaul squiffy black spot yardarm spyglass sheet transom heave to.</p><br />
<p>Trysail Sail ho Corsair red ensign hulk smartly boom jib rum gangway. Case shot Shiver me timbers gangplank crack Jennys tea cup ballast Blimey lee snow crow's nest rutters. Fluke jib scourge of the seven seas boatswain schooner gaff booty Jack Tar transom spirits.  </p><br />
<p>Prow scuttle parrel provost Sail ho shrouds spirits boom mizzenmast yardarm. Pinnace holystone mizzenmast quarter crow's nest nipperkin grog yardarm hempen halter furl. Swab barque interloper chantey doubloon starboard grog black jack gangway rutters.</p><br />
<p>Deadlights jack lad schooner scallywag dance the hempen jig carouser broadside cable strike colors. Bring a spring upon her cable holystone blow the man down spanker Shiver me timbers to go on account lookout wherry doubloon chase. Belay yo-ho-ho keelhaul squiffy black spot yardarm spyglass sheet transom heave to.</p><br />
<p>Trysail Sail ho Corsair red ensign hulk smartly boom jib rum gangway. Case shot Shiver me timbers gangplank crack Jennys tea cup ballast Blimey lee snow crow's nest rutters. Fluke jib scourge of the seven seas boatswain schooner gaff booty Jack Tar transom spirits.  </p><br />
<p>Prow scuttle parrel provost Sail ho shrouds spirits boom mizzenmast yardarm. Pinnace holystone mizzenmast quarter crow's nest nipperkin grog yardarm hempen halter furl. Swab barque interloper chantey doubloon starboard grog black jack gangway rutters.</p><br />
<p>Deadlights jack lad schooner scallywag dance the hempen jig carouser broadside cable strike colors. Bring a spring upon her cable holystone blow the man down spanker Shiver me timbers to go on account lookout wherry doubloon chase. Belay yo-ho-ho keelhaul squiffy black spot yardarm spyglass sheet transom heave to.</p><br />
<p>Trysail Sail ho Corsair red ensign hulk smartly boom jib rum gangway. Case shot Shiver me timbers gangplank crack Jennys tea cup ballast Blimey lee snow crow's nest rutters. Fluke jib scourge of the seven seas boatswain schooner gaff booty Jack Tar transom spirits.  </p><br />  
        </p>      
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
      <div class="right affix">
        <div class="well col-xs-12">
          <h2>RIGHT DIV</h2>
<p>Prow scuttle parrel provost Sail ho shrouds spirits boom mizzenmast yardarm. Pinnace holystone mizzenmast quarter crow's nest nipperkin grog yardarm hempen halter furl. Swab barque interloper chantey doubloon starboard grog black jack gangway rutters.</p><br />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

See also:
[Bootstrap Right and Left Sidebars Fixed snippet](https://www.bootply.com/101100)

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```css
/* Using this CSS is giving me unexpected result.*/

.main {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.col-lg-3 {
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
}

.col-lg-6 {
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    LEFT DIV
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    MIDDLE DIV
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    RIGHT DIV
  </div>
</div>
```

try this `jsfiddle code` : [code for center div scroll](https://jsfiddle.net/BhargavChudasama/g4nfec7g/)